# Operation on spark streaming Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, streaming

iam using a spark streaming pipeline which receive data from a source, this data is loaded as a data frame.
I have some business logic to apply on this streaming dataframe ( control) and according to the result, I write stream the data frame in a different output path.
For exemple :
If my Df is empty or one of his column is empty, I will put the df on path named A
If my Df is not empty and all column too, I will put it on path named B.
The issue is my dataframe is a Streaming Dataframe, so I can’t apply function like : Df.isempty()…
Can u tell me if there is a way to make operation like this on a streaming Dataframe ?
Nb: iam using spark 2.3
Thank. A lot !

Answer (score 0):

In Spark 2.3.0, you can use the [foreach Sink](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach) of [Spark Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) to apply your checks on the data. For this you'd have to implement an instance of `ForeachWrite[T]` class and fill in the logic of how you create connection and how would you write your data (each record separately). Following is the structure of it:

```
dataFrame.writeStream.foreach(new ForeachWriter[Row] {

  def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
    // open connection
  }

  def process(record: Row) = {
    // write string to connection
  }

  def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
    // close the connection
  }
})
```

In the process method, you will have to add the logic to write each row of your DataFrame. Here you can enter your checks accordingly. A sample implementation can be found [here](https://www.programcreek.com/scala/org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter).

**There is a better alternative:**

If you can switch your Spark version to 2.4.x or greater then this becomes quite simple as you can directly leverage the [foreachBatch Sink](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#foreachbatch) of [Spark Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html). Here is how it looks:

```
streamingDF.writeStream.foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
  // Transform and write batchDF 
}.start()
```

So, after using foreachBatch we are getting a nonStreaming DataFrame here as `batchDF` and all of the non streaming computations like checks for empty/non-empty can be applied. According to the checks, you can add the logic to write the DataFrame to required path.

PS: I have added my answer assuming that you are working with [Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) in Spark not with [Spark Streaming(DStreams)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/streaming-programming-guide.html) as you are mentioning Streaming DataFrames. This answer will not actually apply to the DStream Spark Streaming.

Comment: The thing is after i control my input dataframe, i have to do some operation with it after like join with other sources. so i use the foreach, i'have to start() and stop() the streaming query at the control stage...

Comment: Also, i wanted to write the output as a csv, which i thnik is not possible using foreach sink..